# Views results diplay modes

Tags: views

I have a view with its filters exposed. when someone searches for any content results are shown perfectly in list view . now wat i want is a link showing grid view of the same result. more apecific i want a result to be in 2 modes  1) list view and another one is the grid view.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating two different display of same view. If your current view display is page at path like `/view/list-view` then create another page display of same view with path like `/view/grid-view`. Then Configure that display as Grid view under views `Format` settings. You can use that path to create link to that view later anywhere you want.

[image: Add new gird display of view]